# Strange behavior when adding SerializeField to a variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok first of all I'm not sure I added the right title to this question, if you think it might be confusing then I'll change it.

In a scene I have a LevelManager that spawns three instances of the same object with Instantiate. The instantiated objects have the script written below. The first and the second object are only instantiated, while the third one gets cached and immediately after the LevelManager calls the `IsNowCorrect` function:

```
public class LevelManagerValuesUpdater : MonoBehaviour
{
    ShapeMatch_LevelManager _levelManager;

    Transform _transform;
    Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;

    /*[SerializeField]*/ bool isCorrect = false;

    Vector2 position;
    float rotation;

    public void IsNowCorrect(ShapeMatch_LevelManager levelManager)
    {
        isCorrect = true;

        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " is correct");
    
        _levelManager = levelManager;
        AssignComponents();
    }

    void AssignComponents()
    {
        _transform = gameObject.transform;
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isCorrect)
            return;

        Debug.Log("Update ran");

        position = _transform.position;
        rotation = _rigidbody.rotation;

        _levelManager.UpdateInfo(position, rotation);
    }
}
```

The first part of the script runs just fine. The first Debug.Log  (the one inside `NowIsCorrect`) gets called only by the last of the three objects as you would expect. But then neither of the three runs the second Debug.Log in the Update function.

I tried to add a `[SerializeField]` to the `isCorrect` variable to check it from the Inspector and this happened: the variable on the third object was true and the first Log was called once (just as before), but the Debug.Log in Update now was called by all of the three objects. On top of that, now I get a NullReference Exception by all the three objects, as if the `AssignComponents` function doesn't get called (but if you put a Debug.Log inside of it looks like it IS called)

I'm sorry if I'm just missing something trivial but I can't get my head around this for now...

Comment: Is the script enabled ? If not, the update method won't get called. Tick the little box on the top left corner of your MonoBehaviour within the inspector

Comment: @Malphegal of course it is enable. If you think about it, if it wasn't I wouldn't get the NullReferenceException errors

Answer (score -1):

For anybody having the same issue
Turns out that when the objects were instanciated the `isCorrect` defaulted to true for some reason (even if I made it false durung declaration) so I made so that is becomes false again as soon as Awake is called.